# Show onclick on nested array

Tags: arrays, angular, onclick

I got an array with teams and in that array an array with players.

**Json file**

```
"id": 1,
"Name": "TEAM A",
"Active": true,
"created_at": "2019-09-12T13:56:52.045Z",
"updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.533Z",
"Players": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "Name": "PLAYER1",
    "Active": null,
    "created_at": "2019-09-12T13:56:41.496Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.540Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "Name": "PLAYER2",
    "Active": true,
    "created_at": "2019-09-12T14:00:12.149Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.540Z"
  }
```

I've created a button to open all players within the parent (team).

**HTML**

```
<button (click)="hidden = !hidden" href="#">{{!hidden ? 'Show players' : 'Hide players'}}</button>
    <hr>
     <ul>
      <li *ngFor='let team of teams'>{{ team.Name }} (id: {{ team.id }})
        <ng-container *ngIf="hidden" class="hidden">
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let player of team.Players">{{ player.Name }} ({{ player.id }})</li>
            </ul>
        </ng-container>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Now, when I click that button, it will show all childs (players) of each team.

**Question**
I would really like to make this clickfunction on the team itself so that only the items of the chosen team will be openend instead of all. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You need an unique identifier for each team, now you are using just one variable, which of course expands all.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a variable attach some property to your team model and use that to hide/show player so your code should be like

```
<li *ngFor='let team of teams' (click)="team.showPlayers=!team.showPlayers">{{ team.Name }} (id: {{ team.id }})
        <ng-container *ngIf="team.showPlayers">
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let player of team.Players">{{ player.Name }} ({{ player.id }})</li>
            </ul>
        </ng-container>
      </li>
```

don't forgot to add `showPlayers` property to team model else you may get error in your prod build

[working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fn6jdy)

Answer (score 0):

HTML Template

```
<li *ngFor='let team of teams' (click)="team.showTeam=!team.showTeam">{{ team.Name }} (id: {{ team.id }})
        <ul *ngIf="team.showTeam">
            <li *ngFor="let player of team.Players">{{ player.Name }} ({{ player.id }})</li>
        </ul>
</li>
```

Teams Array

```
teams: Array<any> = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "Name": "TEAM A",
      "Active": true,
      "created_at": "2019-09-12T13:56:52.045Z",
      "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.533Z",
      "showTeam":false,
      "Players": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "Name": "PLAYER1",
          "Active": null,
          "created_at": "2019-09-12T13:56:41.496Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.540Z"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "Name": "PLAYER2",
          "Active": true,
          "created_at": "2019-09-12T14:00:12.149Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.540Z"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "Name": "PLAYER3",
          "Active": true,
          "created_at": "2019-09-12T14:00:12.149Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.540Z"
        },{
          "id": 4,
          "Name": "PLAYER4",
          "Active": true,
          "created_at": "2019-09-12T14:00:12.149Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.540Z"
        },{
          "id": 5,
          "Name": "PLAYER5",
          "Active": true,
          "created_at": "2019-09-12T14:00:12.149Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.540Z"
        },
        {
          "id": 6,
          "Name": "PLAYER6",
          "Active": true,
          "created_at": "2019-09-12T14:00:12.149Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.540Z"
        },
        {
          "id": 7,
          "Name": "PLAYER7",
          "Active": true,
          "created_at": "2019-09-12T14:00:12.149Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.540Z"
        },
        {
          "id": 8,
          "Name": "PLAYER8",
          "Active": true,
          "created_at": "2019-09-12T14:00:12.149Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.540Z"
        },
        {
          "id": 9,
          "Name": "PLAYER9",
          "Active": true,
          "created_at": "2019-09-12T14:00:12.149Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.540Z"
        }
        ,{
          "id": 10,
          "Name": "PLAYER10",
          "Active": true,
          "created_at": "2019-09-12T14:00:12.149Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.540Z"
        },
        {
          "id": 11,
          "Name": "PLAYER11",
          "Active": true,
          "created_at": "2019-09-12T14:00:12.149Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.540Z"
        },
        {
          "id": 12,
          "Name": "PLAYER12",
          "Active": true,
          "created_at": "2019-09-12T14:00:12.149Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.540Z"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "Name": "TEAM B",
      "Active": true,
      "showTeam":false,
      "created_at": "2019-09-12T13:56:52.045Z",
      "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.533Z",
      "Players": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "Name": "PLAYER1",
          "Active": null,
          "created_at": "2019-09-12T13:56:41.496Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.540Z"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "Name": "PLAYER2",
          "Active": true,
          "created_at": "2019-09-12T14:00:12.149Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.540Z"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "Name": "PLAYER3",
          "Active": true,
          "created_at": "2019-09-12T14:00:12.149Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.540Z"
        },{
          "id": 4,
          "Name": "PLAYER4",
          "Active": true,
          "created_at": "2019-09-12T14:00:12.149Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.540Z"
        },{
          "id": 5,
          "Name": "PLAYER5",
          "Active": true,
          "created_at": "2019-09-12T14:00:12.149Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.540Z"
        },
        {
          "id": 6,
          "Name": "PLAYER6",
          "Active": true,
          "created_at": "2019-09-12T14:00:12.149Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.540Z"
        },
        {
          "id": 7,
          "Name": "PLAYER7",
          "Active": true,
          "created_at": "2019-09-12T14:00:12.149Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.540Z"
        },
        {
          "id": 8,
          "Name": "PLAYER8",
          "Active": true,
          "created_at": "2019-09-12T14:00:12.149Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.540Z"
        },
        {
          "id": 9,
          "Name": "PLAYER9",
          "Active": true,
          "created_at": "2019-09-12T14:00:12.149Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.540Z"
        }
        ,{
          "id": 10,
          "Name": "PLAYER10",
          "Active": true,
          "created_at": "2019-09-12T14:00:12.149Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.540Z"
        },
        {
          "id": 11,
          "Name": "PLAYER11",
          "Active": true,
          "created_at": "2019-09-12T14:00:12.149Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.540Z"
        },
        {
          "id": 12,
          "Name": "PLAYER12",
          "Active": true,
          "created_at": "2019-09-12T14:00:12.149Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.540Z"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```